# python manage.py dbshell doesn't find psycopg2 although it is installed and in path

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2, mezzanine

I'd like to be issuing SQL commands via python manage.py dbshell but I get the error "CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path". From the python prompt I can import psycopg2 without getting any errors and psycopg2 appears to be in my python path.

I'm trying django and my settings.py specifies "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2"

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks, Julian

Answer (score 1):

when you run `./manage.py dbshell psql or sqlite3` this command assumes the programs are on your *PATH*. this will simply calls the program name.

**sqlite3**

from Python itself dosen't contain a `sqlite3` command. if you want to access from the command line you have to install  SQLite library that includes a `simple command-line` utility named `sqlite3`. but without installing library you can create the db server because  it doesn’t require running a separate server and sqlite3 itself a text based file.

If you are developing a simple project or something you don’t plan to deploy in a production environment, then use `SQLite`

in your case first install sqlite3 using  `sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev` to access dbshell.

**postgres**

compare to `sqlite3` this `postgres` needs package to initialize. postgresql need [postgresql_psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/) package

Comment: Hi - postgres is the database that I'm ultimately going to be using, so I'd like to stick with that rather than sqlite3. Running psql works fine from any directory so I guess that is on my PATH. As I mentioned, I think psycopg2 is also installed OK as I can run "import psycopg2" without errors from the python prompt. Running ./manage.py dbshell psql gives a list of errors culminating in: `output = self.handle(*args, **options)
TypeError: handle() takes exactly 1 argument (7 given)` Thanks for your help

Comment: @JulianJordan you never mentioned in your question when running `dbshell psql` gives error`

Comment: Hi - I didn't know until your helpful answer that I could specify psql on the end of `./manage.py dbshell` so that in itself has been helpful, as until then I'd been getting an error relating to sqlite3 (presumably the default option?)

Comment: Oh ,.. so now `dbshell psql` gives you this error `output = self.handle(*args, **options) TypeError: handle() takes exactly 1 argument (7 given)` am i right ?

Comment: Hi - specifying the name of my database after dbshell psql gives a similar error: `output = self.handle(*args, **options)
TypeError: handle() takes exactly 1 argument (8 given)`

Comment: @JulianJordan oh . okay .. let's give like this `dbshell psql --database=default` try default first if it's fails try actual db name..

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work either. My main aim at the moment is to get through the django tutorial so I've made a new setup using sqlite3 which "just works". Ultimately I'm going to have to use postgres but I think for now I'll use the easier db setup. Thanks for your suggestions :o)

Comment: @JulianJordan please read this questin before procede [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776709/setting-up-postgresql-with-django-project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776709/setting-up-postgresql-with-django-project),.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install sqlite3 to be able to run dbshell

Installing the sqlite program should solve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion as to what dbshell does. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#dbshell):

> Runs the command-line client for the database engine specified in your
>   ENGINE setting, with the connection parameters specified in your USER,
>   PASSWORD, etc., settings.
>
> - For PostgreSQL, this runs the `psql` command-line client.
> - For MySQL,
>     this runs the `mysql` command-line client.
> - For SQLite, this runs the
>     `sqlite3` command-line client.
>
> This command assumes the programs are on your PATH so that a simple
>   call to the program name (psql, mysql, sqlite3) will find the program
>   in the right place. There’s no way to specify the location of the
>   program manually.

Its not like `manage.py shell`, `dbshell` just runs the normal shell for the database configured, except it logs you in with the credentials in `settings.py`.

This means, if you are using postgresql, you need to have the `psql` command already installed in order for `dbshell` to work. This command is not part of Python, but comes with the postgresql server.

In order words - if all you have installed is psycopg2, the `dbshell` command will not work.

Comment: Hi - I do have the psql command installed, and running it gives me the postgres prompt: username=#

Comment: Please update the question with your `settings.py` file.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Question itself quite unclear.. though now we have `TypeError`

Comment: I've obscured the username/password in settings.py and posted it here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23754608/settings.py (it's too long to post here directly, is there a better way?)