# CommandError: You appear not to have the 'psql' program installed or on your path

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-settings, django-database

I'm using Windows, no virtualenv.  I have psycopg2 installed with Pip, and the latest version of PostgreSQL installed as well.

When I run `./ manage.py dbshell`, I get the following error:

```
CommandError: You appear not to have the 'psql' program installed or on your path.
```

When I run `./ manage.py dbshell psql`, I get this:

```
usage: manage.py dbshell [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS]
                         [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color]
                         [--database DATABASE]
manage.py dbshell: error: unrecognized arguments: psql
```

I have read a few other posts on this error like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037208/python-manage-py-dbshell-doesnt-find-psycopg2-although-it-is-installed-and-in-p) but I don't understand why this is not working for me.  I have all the settings properly configured, and all the proper apps installed.

My settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '********',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

EDIT: I did not add Postgres's /bin folder into my PATH.  I just did it and it is working now.  Thanks to Daniel Roseman.

Comment: Well, is it on your path? What happens if you just run `psql`?

Comment: Don't forget to restart the command prompt after you have updated the PATH environment variable to reflect the changes.

Comment: @Valachio how did you solved it finally??

Answer (score 5):

In Windows I solved by adding this to PATH environment:

`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin`

then restart terminals and IDEs

[Path Environment PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfJAL.png)

[How to add a folder to `Path` environment variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error on **Windows 11**:

> python manage.py dbshell
>
> CommandError: You appear not to have the 'psql' program installed or
> on your path.

Even though I installed **"psycopg2"**:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

So, I added **the path "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<version>\bin"** to **`Path` of `User variables` or `System variables` which are under `Environment Variables`**, then I could solve the error. *In my case, **<version>** is **`14`** as shown below:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

For mac, run command `brew install postgres`.

In case, your machine don't have brew installed, follow [this](https://brew.sh/) to install brew. Or run command

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score -2):

Is postgresql installed on your machine.

Apart from:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

you need to install postgres:

```
sudo apt-get install postgres
```

Comment: Maybe you mean `sudo apt-get install postgresql` ?